# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Check Font Size

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check a documents body text (excluding headers) is 12, and if it's not return a messaging saying so.

However it is also recognizing the header size as well and I can't find a way to change this.

Here is my code so far

```
public class CheckFontSize : IPlugin_Document
    {


        public string GetDescription()
        {
            return "Checks whether body text is font size 12";
        }

        public string GetName()
        {
            return "Check Font size";
        }


        public void Run(Document doc, MessageFeedManager messageFeed)
        {
            AddMessageToFeed.Write("Current Task", " Checking font size...", GetName(), messageFeed);
            var FindSize = doc.Content.Font.Size;
            if (FindSize == 12)
            {
                AddMessageToFeed.Write("Current Task", "Font size is correct", GetName(), messageFeed);

            } else
            {
                AddMessageToFeed.Write("Current Task", "Font size is incorrect please change to 12", GetName(), messageFeed);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Document.Content.Font.Size` won't help you when a document has multiple runs of text with different style rules applied. You need to walk the document structure and look at each `Run`.

Comment: I will have a look into it further thanks Dai